# In Outlook, will changing POP3 server settings delete existing inbox emails?

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office

I've recently moved my web and email hosting to a new supplier and am ready to repoint my Domain name from the old host to the new one.

My worry is that when a change the POP3 and SMTP server settings on my Outlook accounts, the mail boxes will either empty or become unreadable in some way.

The email address will be the same, e.g.

```
bob@domain.com
```

but the underling servers will be different, e.g.

```
pop3.oldhost.com --> pop3.newhost.com
```

Will the emails retrieved from the new host simply start accumulating in my existing Outlook inbox, or will it start putting them in a different place?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Existing messages will not be deleted. But this is not a programming question.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - Thanks.  Is there a better place to ask these types of questions?

Comment: Yes, https://superuser.com/